# ¿Se puede hacer un programa para iniciar sesión pero para que lo haga tenga que registrarme?

Tags: delphi

Lo que quiero hacer es como si fuera un facebook, para crearte uno tienes que registrarte porque no hay cuenta existente para iniciar sesión, quiero hacer eso mismo pero en delphi hacer un programa que me permita registrarme antes de iniciar sesión y si no estoy registrado que no me reconozca los datos que ponga cuando vaya a iniciar sesión ahora, ¿es eso posible en delphi?.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No me ha quedado claro qué es lo que quieres hacer exactamente, pero si quieres solo experimentar cómo funciona un formulario de registro e inicio de sesión, delphi no es el lenguaje más adecuado. Además, necesitarás una pequeña base de datos. Te dejo un enlace con información para empezar: [https://www.freelancer.es/community/articles/que-lenguaje-programacion-web-debo-aprender]

Comment: Muchas Gracias por contestar, tengo un problema y es que el link que me enviaste me dice que parece que la pagina que estoy buscando no existe pero en fin es eso exactamente lo que quiero hacer un formulario de registro e inicio de sesión pero cuando dijiste no es el mas adecuado es que se puede hacer en delphi? o es muy complicado?, me gustaría que me enseñaras como hacerlo si fuese posible en ese lenguaje de programación.

Comment: Perdona, se me colaron los corchetes en el enlace, borra solo el corchete final del enlace y accederás a la página. Con respecto a delphi, no lo conozco en profundidad, pero no le visto en ninguna parte ningún modo de hacer lo que necesitas usando delphi. He encontrado otro enlace que te enseñan a hacer algunas aplicaciones web usando ese lenguaje: http://www.danysoft.com/free/apwd.pdf   por si te interesa, pero nada más. Aún así, te recomiendo que mires el enlace anterior y aprendas otros lenguajes si lo que te interesa realmente es la programación web, te valdrá la pena el esfuerzo ;)

Comment: Muchas Gracias por responder y gracias por el contenido, se te agradece :) xD

Comment: Delphi puede ser o no el adecuado dependiendo de lo que quieres conseguir. Ahora, tu pregunta parece demasiado amplia para el formato del sitio. ¿Qué has intentado? ¿cuál es el problema específico que tienes hasta ahora?

Comment: honestamente no tengo idea de como hacer eso posible no hace mucho así como miguelw un amigo me dijo que se puede hacer con una base de datos pero de saber como podría conectarlo con la base de datos no lo sé. Y en fin ese es el problema por lo que me detiene de hacer algo ya que eso es lo principal. tengo un formulario de inicio de sesión pero tengo otro que es para registrarme por si no tengo una cuenta para iniciar sesión y obvio que no tendré una cuenta entonces tendré que ir al formulario de registro para poner mis datos y crearme una cuenta como un facebook.